# How to make this script more efficient

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I make this script more efficient to achieve the exact same output plot? Ie, reduce the number of for loops etc.
Ideas that come to mind are list comprehension, lambda expressions, "*="...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = np.array(l)
l2 = [10,20,30,40,50]
l2 = np.array(l2)

t = [3,4,5]

f = []
for i in t:
    l1=l*(i)
    f.append(l1)
    
for i in range(len(f)):
    plt.plot(l1, f[i])
    
f = []
for i in t:
    l3=l2*(i)
    f.append(l3)

for i in range(len(f)):
    plt.plot(l3, f[i])
```

Comment: I think you will get more useful help, if you could explain what you are trying to achive.

Comment: At both `plot` commands you use the list created beforehand as x-values e.g. `plt.plot(l1, f[i])` with `l1`. Is this by design, since you will always use the last one created. You could use `f[-1]` instead.

Comment: Since l and l2 are not linked, you could parallelize it.
https://youtu.be/fKl2JW_qrso

You can also use :
`for i in f:
    plt.plot(l1,i)`
To have something cleaner

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create your data as 2D numpy arrays
2. Then you can plot these 2D arrays in one call to [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

> If x and/or y are 2D arrays a separate data set will be drawn for
> every column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
l2 = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
t = [3,4,5]

plt.plot(l * t[-1], l[:, None] * t)
plt.plot(l2 * t[-1], l2[:, None] * t)
```

[image]